# Method to automate collection of data from Excel?

Tags: .net, excel, .net-4.0, excel-2007, wrapper

I have an Excel plugin which pipes realtime data into my Excel application.

What is the easiest method to get this data into a .NET application?

Ideally, there would be some method to embed the .xll file (the actual Excel plugin) into your .NET app, and some method to call the functionality of the .xll file. Failing that, are there any methods to automate Excel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ideally you would want to bypass the Excel plugin and get the data directly from the source.

If this isn't an option, you could use the Office Interop to fire event handlers in your code whenever the cells in an Excel document change. Please see this [this MSDN article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/823981) for a good example.

Another possibility would be to use the commercial [MangedXLL](http://www.stochastix.de/solutions/excel/managedxll/latest/) library.